Older Android phones? App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or later
Well I got the notice for "App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or later" so I update the target and compile Sdkversion.
The problem is that now a large number of users cannot receive an update and the application doesn't appear in Play Store for them anymore.
My question is am I doing something wrong or is it the expected behaviour and Google is kind of forcing users to eventually upgrade their phones to newer models?

targetSdk has nothing to do with your minSdkVersion, none of your users lose access to your device because you change your targetSdk

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm glad you asked this. I only started mobile development (via flutter) and this wasn't obvious to me.

To explain this in a bit more detail than the comment, there are two values here:
minSDKVersion-  the minimum version of Android needed to use the app.
targetSDKVersion-  the version of the SDK used to compile the app.  This controls how several APIs behave.
You need to have a 34 or later for targetSDKVersion.  You can have whatever you want for minSDKVersion.  It's minSDKVersion that controls how old of a phone you can support.  If devices stopped seeing your app, you changed the minSDKVersion when you didn't need to.  Change it back and reupload.

Makes sense. I changed the minSDKVersion as well. I feed stupid for not thinking this was the cause. Thank you!

Android 14 refuses to install apps targeting APIs before 23 (before Android 6.0) and Android 15 refuses to install apps targeting APIs before 24 (before Android 7.0)

As mention by Gabe Sechan, the reason for my issue was that I had updated the both targetDSKVersion and minSDKVersion to value 34 in build.gradle file.
As a result, my application was restricted to less than 2,000 Android devices.
Only the targetSDKVersion needs to be updated in order to comply with Google Play Policy.
By restoring the value of minSDKVersion to the original value, my application is now available to more than 15k devices.
